# How to handle tags for generically-named software?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Currently the [workday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workday) tag is in regards the software Workday (with a capital `W`). However, a few of the questions tagged with it are regarding workdays (with a lower-case `w`). This seems kind of horribly prone to mis-tagging, but I'm not sure what the appropriate course of action here is (I haven't had much to do with managing tags before). What do we normally do when companies name their software with annoyingly-generic words?

Should we change the Workday software tag to [workday-something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workday-something)? Or do we just leave it and resign ourselves to cleaning it up on an ongoing basis?

Comment: This doesn't rule out changing the tag to something less ambiguous, but it is worth noting that lower-case "workday" probably doesn't deserve a tag.

Comment: Did you already clean it up? I can't find very many questions tagged [tag:workday] that appear to be about something other than the software. The only one I see is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188487/cakephp-select-count-number-of-days), which does in fact need to be retagged, but more importantly, needs to be closed and deleted. This sounds like a theoretical problem to me, rather than an actual one. We don't need to append "-software" to all of our tags, as it should be implied. Off-topic questions are inevitably going to be asked, no matter how perfect our tag system.

Comment: This sounds like a company rather than a product.

Comment: @CodyGray when I asked there were about five questions- but I asked because it came up in my edit queue , so someone else may well have done it

Comment: It was all being used for the API, so I renamed it as [workday-api], and added [workday] as a synonym.